# How do I save a Tensorflow LinearClassifier model and convert it to Tensorflow.js compatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

I have recently started using tensorflow, and I have just a simple LinearClassifier model. And I want to save it and then convert the saved model using [tfjs-converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter)

But the problem is that I can't seem to complete the first step of saving the model without errors.

Below is a snippet of my code.

```py
linear_est = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns)

linear_est.train(train_input_fn)  # train

linear_est.save('saved_model/my_model') # This gives an error
```

Any help on getting unstuck is greatly appreciated!

Comment: To save an Estimator, you need to use `tf.Estimator.export_saved_model`. You can find an example here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/estimator#savedmodels_from_estimators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in the comment didn't work for me, but I followed the instructions and settled upon something like this

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflowjs as tfjs

input_column = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x")
a = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(input_column)

serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
  tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec([input_column]))

# Save Estimator as a tf model
a.export_saved_model("modelFromEstimator/", serving_input_fn)

# Import model as keras model
model = keras.models.load_model("modelFromEstimator/")

# Save as tfjs model
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, "tfjsmodel")
```

Tensorflow's example for making a basic linear estimator crashed when I tried to run it. You don't have to use Estimators to do machine learning — it seems like they're still in development currently.

If you're just getting started with Tensorflow, you might want to start with `keras.models` like [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner).

Comment: I am having an issue, when it comes to create the serving_input_fn. I have multiple input columns and i appended them into one single list. And when I try to use that list to create serving_input_fn I get an error saying "ValueError: All feature_columns must be FeatureColumn instances."

Comment: Instead of using the column names in a list, try converting them to FeatureColumns first with `tf.feature_column.numeric_column("feature")` before appending them all to a list.